# How to get the value of inner html data for storing the value to database

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

How do I get this JavaScript variable data to PHP, so that I can insert Latitude and Longitude data to the database or any other way to get the user's location and store it in the database.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>
  <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
      }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
      x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What JavaScript data?

Comment: function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}

how can I send this data to php

Comment: You'd most likely post it with form data. Have your JS interact with a form element (hidden or otherwise). Other options are an ajax call to your own php script handeling the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like you need to use AJAX to pass the value of your javascript variable to PHP.

In your HTML file (index.html)

index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
  function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
      x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
  }

  function showPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;

    //AJAX CALL THIS WILL PASS THE VALUE OF JAVASCRIPT TO PHP
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'ajax-processor.php',
      data: {
        lat: lat,
        long: long
      },
      success: function(html) {
        alert("Success");
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

In your ajax file (ajax-processor.php)

```
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$long = $_POST['long'];

//your code to insert to the database here using the $lat and $long variable
```

Make sure that the URL for the PHP file is correct.

You may read more about AJAX and how to pass data from JavaScript to PHP in my blog post: https://www.davidangulo.xyz/website-development/how-to-pass-value-from-javascript-to-php/

Comment: Yes, @David Angulo, I got it. Thank you for your help